# For targeted standard and dotnetcore library which dll will be selected in core application?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I have a library, that target NETSTANDARD2_0 that used by full NET461 and NETCOREAPP2_0 clients.

I want to add to the library some Core2.0 specific code.
I am going to add APPNETCORE2_0 target and wrap the section with

```
#if NETCOREAPP2_0 
#endif
```

It will create 2 separate target DLLs.
When I will refer my library from client Core2.0 application , will it refer NETCOREAPP2_0 DLL and ignore NETSTANDARD2_0 dll?

Is the order of selecting the version predefined and documented?
I will appreciate a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official [doc on creating these multi-targetted dlls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries). That explains how a different dll is generated for each target (such as `net461` and `netcoreapp1.0`).

The official [doc on how nuget resolves these to find the matching library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#matching-assembly-versions-and-the-target-framework-in-a-project) covers how the right dll is selected:

> When NuGet installs a package that has multiple assembly versions, it tries to match the framework name of the assembly with the target framework of the project.
>
> If a match is not found, NuGet copies the assembly for the highest version that is less than or equal to the project's target framework, if available. If no compatible assembly is found, NuGet returns an appropriate error message.

Side note: you want `NETCOREAPP2_0`, not `APPNETCORE2_0`.

Comment: "NuGet copies the assembly for the highest version that is less than or equal to the project's target framework".    
For  netcoreapp2.0 application if netcoreapp2.0 lib not found, will  netstandard2.0 lib be used?

Comment: Yes. You can see the complete logic in NuGet's sources here: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs#L367-L370

Comment: Thanks, source code is a definitive source of truth